# Select from MySQL WHERE IN [values array]

Tags: javascript, mysql, typeorm

I need to make a select from MySQL with the selection values in an array. I have data like this:

```
const CompaniesRelation = [{CompanyId: ""},{CompanyId: ""},{CompanyId: ""},{CompanyId: ""},{CompanyId: ""}];
```

With Companies Relation I need to select/find, I need to get all the information for each CompanyId's:

```
 const Companies: Array<Company> = await getRepository(Company).find({ where:{ CompanyId: CompaniesRelation[0].CompanyId, IsActive: true} });
```

I'm using TypeOrm in Angular. I need to select the information for each object into CompaniesRelation. I need to use fewest selects to DB, in other words, foreach is not the way.

For the final result I need to have an array with all the information of each company in Companies Relation, like this:

```
[{CompanyId: "", Name: "", fk:""},{CompanyId: "", Name: "", fk:""},{CompanyId: "", Name: "", fk:""}]
```

Comment: Typeorm also has the IN operator.

Comment: @JonasWilms Do you have an example or link of sintaxys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How you use WHERE x IN explained in [find options](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/find-options.md) for find*, and [adding WHERE expression](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/select-query-builder.md#adding-where-expression) for QueryBuilder.

First get your Company Ids into an array of integers:

```
const companyIds = [1, 2, 3];
```

or

```
const companySel = [{ CompanyId: 1 }, { CompanyId: 2 }, { CompanyId: 3 }];
const companyIds = companySel.map(a => a.CompanyId);
```

Then you can use the In operator with find

```
import {In} from "typeorm";

const companyList = await getRepository(Company)
  .find({ where: { CompanyId: In (companyIds ) } });
```

Or you can use the TypeOrm QueryBuilder with "IN" (note the `:...` syntax)

```
const companyList = await getRepository(Company)
  .createQueryBuilder()
  .where("CompanyId IN (:...ids )", { ids: companyIds ) })
  .getMany();
```

Comment: Didn't find anywhere documentation on :... syntax, thanks you !

Comment: @Edward  Please explain why we need the spread operator.

Comment: @AbdullahKhan We need the spread operator because without it the query builder passes a single (array) parameter like this: WHERE id in (@0) -- PARAMETERS: [[1,2,3]]; this does not work. With the spread operator it splits each item in the array into individual parameters like this: WHERE id in (@0, @1, @2) -- PARAMETERS: [1,2,3]; this works.